Transimpedance amplifier with OPA838 - instability
I have the following circuit as a transimpedance amplifier for ultrasound application:

I checked all the possible criteria for the stability of the circuit, including phase margin, step response overshoot,....., and all of them confirm the circuit should be stable, following we see the diagram bode as well. As it is clear there is an picking in the bode diagram around 30MHz.

I have 64 of this amplifier design on my PCB. I have used 5 decoupling capacitor for each Amplifier, two 100nF for +/- and two 2.2 uF for +/- and one 100 nF between positive and negative rail. When I apply +/-3 V to the circuit the PCB draws about 700mA current (e.g. 350mA form positive rail and 350mA from negative rail). In fact the circuit should consumes 64mA form positive rail and 64mA form negative rail based on the datasheet of the OPA838. Besides, I noticed all the Op-Amps are unstable and oscillates. But, when I reduce the supply voltage to +/- 1V everything is nominal and the current consumption is about 64mA from each rail and non of the Op-amps are unstable. Would you please let me know why is that? based on the datasheet the supply voltage can be +/-2.5V?!
Would you please let me know how can I make the circuit stable in +/-2.5V? and what is the root cause for this instability?

Are the sensors attached when performing these tests? The OPA838 is not unity gain stable, it needs the capacitance of the sensor to bring the loop gain to the point where it is stable.

Hello Kevin, thank you for the nice comment.  No for my initial tests the sensor was not attached to the OPA838, do you think if I attached the sensor it will be stable even with +/- 2.5 V?

If the sensor model is accurate and it does have 1nf of capacitance that should bring the loop gain to a stable point. For testing you could just replace the sensor with a 1nF capacitor.

@Kevin, thank you vey much for the guidance, so I will use a capacitor and let you the results, one pin of the 1nF cap with be tied to the inverting input of the OPA838, and the other pin will be tied to GND? right?

As it is clear in the schematic as well, you can see that, there is a DC blocking Cap (10 nF) between the OPA838 and the sensor, do you think I can directly connect that Cap (10 nF) to ground for a quick test??

@Kevin White As an update I connected the transducer and it was still oscillating, I used also a 1nF Cap, instead of the transducer, and it was still oscillating. it is not oscillating if I use +/-1V for the supply or (V-=0&V+=3.5V)->not using any negative supply, so I wonder what is  the reason, that it is very dependent to the supply voltage and the negative rail .

As others have indicated - +/- 1V is below the allowed operating supply of the OPA838. That opamp has a very high GBW so requires extremely good PCB layout, especially regarding supply decoupling. You need to ensure that there is very low inductance between the device supply pins and the capacitors.

@Kevin White would you please see my layout in here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/708779/transimpedance-amplifier-with-opa838-oscillation-supply-voltage

Hello @ Kevin White I also noticed the output of the OPA838 is connected to a connector for measurement (No load is connected to OPA838) and the trace on the PCB has a capacitance around 170 pF, can this cause the instability? if yes, how can I do a quick test? to verify this is the issue?

170pF - that is extremely large and could cause instability by increasing the phase shift at the output in conjunction with the opacmpp output impedance. Isolate that trace/connector with a 50 ohm resistor (value not critical) close to the opamp.

Hello @ Kevin White I noticed my calculator shows 171pF per meter length (0.171pF/mm), the length is 110mm, so it would be18 PF. Would you please let me know that one ne side of the 50 ohm resistor should be connected to the OPA838  output and the other side to GND?

You put the resistor in series with the load after the feedback resistor/capacitor but before any significant capacitance load. I don't expect 18pF would don't be a problem though. Be careful about using x1 scope probes as they have a very high input capacitance, maybe 100pF. A x10 probe will be ~10pF and should not cause a problem.


When I apply +/-3 V to the circuit the PCB draws about 700mA current

The data sheet says this: -
Single-supply operating range: 2.7 V to 5.4 V

It also says this: -

So, there's a reasonable possibility that you have over-stressed the op-amps by applying 6 volts.
The data sheet also says this: -
Operating at the minimum recommended noninverting
gain of 6 V/V results in a 90-MHz, –3-dB bandwidth.

You may not be meeting this requirement in your design if C4 (1 nF) is actually lower than this. For instance, if C4 were as low as 372 pF then, you would be on the cusp of instability. Now, I can't tell whether C4 is something that is internal to the ultrasound transducer or not so, maybe you can clarify.

Thank you very much Andy for the helpful comment, already spotted this, and then decided to reduce the voltage, but I noticed it is only stable around +/-1V, should not it be stable also for +/- 2V as well?  is the Op-amp now fully ON with +/- 1V? and do you think I don not have stability problem?

Andy, regarding the C4 yes, it is the internal characteristics of the ultrasound transducer, and we have measured this value, which is around 1nF. But the issue is that even without connecting the transduces to the amplifier (nothing connected to non-inverting input), when we have supply voltage higher than +/1.3 V, the circuit is unstable. Please let me know if you need more data.

@Behnam you must have the transducers connected else the gain becomes unity and the op-amp becomes completely unstable. The minimum gain is 6. C4 at 1 nF ensures that the minimum gain is around 16.

Thank you for the nice guidance, yes, I will try this, so can we conclude like this? when there is no sensor connected to the OPA838 and the supply voltage is around +/- 1V, the OPA838 is not fully ON and do not oscillate (behave like it is stable), but when we increase the voltage higher than +/- 1.2 V, it is fully ON and needs the C4 to make the minimum gain of 6 to be stable? otherwise if the OPA838 is fully ON even with +/- 1V , it means, it is stable even without the C4!?

Would you please let me know how can I calculate this: (The minimum gain is 6. C4 at 1 nF ensures that the minimum gain is around 16), I would like to know how this C4 make the minimum gain 16? what are the formula for this calculations?

@Behnam the feedback capacitor C1 defines the impedance at high frequencies. It is 62 pF. C4 defines the shunting impedance and it is about 16 times bigger so, at the vulnerable area of the spectrum, the gain is about 16. If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

thank you very much for you nice explanation. When there is no sensor connected to the system, there is just C1 (62pF), would you please help me calculate how much gain we have in this situation? it should be lower than 6 it seems, considering the circuit is unstable?!

It will be very close to unity gain. Maybe 1.1. it depends on the parasitic capacitance of your circuit board around the inverting input.

thank you very much for the reply, I plan to remove the sensor and connect 10nF decoupling capacitor to GND, in this cause the gain would be 160 instead of 16? (when it was 1nF we had 16, now it will be 10nF, which is 10 times bigger), I wonder if the circuit will be stable still with this gain? (in this way I can make sure the circuit is stable and the issue is the sensor that is not connected)

Well, it would be better to use a 1 nF capacitor to prove it's stable @Behnam

Thank you, I will do the test and inform you about the result, maybe one more question would be what is the minimum +/- supply voltage that I can apply  to OPA838 and make sure that amplifier is fully ON? (with +/- 1V, I have this feeling that the OPA838 is not fully on yet!?)

@Behnam right at the top of this answer I have stated it. (2.7 volts or +/-1.35 volts)

@ Andy thank you very much you helped me a lot today. My last question would be, currently on my PCB I have this 10nF DC blocking  cap between the sensor and OPA838. Do you think it have have a negative effect in general on the stability? when I add the sensor it will build a 11 nF capacitor on the inverting input of the amplifier (Sensor-1nF+DC blocking 10nF), if it can have a negative input maybe I can reduce to 1 nF?

The two capacitors will be in series not parallel. The resulting capacitance will be 909 pF (an effective gain of 14.66 and fine.

Just wanted to double check with you that the formula for the noise gain is this 1+/.  _ is the transducer cap and _ is the feedback. For example considering there is 1nF in the transducer that is in series with 10nF (DC blocking), we will have 909 pF as _ and 62pF as the _, so the gain would be 15.66, would you please let me know if that is correct?

@Behnam that is the correct formula for noise gain i.e. we assume the noise is wholly contained on the non-inverting input.

@ Andy aka Hello Andy, Today I did the tests, here is my observations. First, When the transducer is connected, (supply voltage +/-2V current consumption form positive rail 360mA, current consumption form negative rail 357mA, considering I have 63 identical OPA838 on my PCB, for each OPA838- 5.7 mA) I saw an oscillation on the output with the frequency around 86MHz, vpp 800mv.  When I remove the transducer, the current consumption increases.

Second, When the transducer is connected, (supply voltage +/-1.5V current consumption form positive rail 236mA, current consumption form negative rail 234mA, I see an oscillation on the output with the frequency around 35MHz, vpp 760mv.

Third, When the transducer is connected, (supply voltage +/-1V current consumption form positive rail 67.9mA, current consumption form positive rail 67.7mA,) I did not see any oscillation on the output.  This part is very interesting, when I use 0V for Negative rail (V-=0&V+=3.5V, the current consumption is 146.7mA and I did not see any oscillation in the output!? Can this be something related to the  negative supply pin?

I just checked the datasheet of the OPA838, for the transimpedance amplifier part, they have used (V-=-230mV, V+= 3V) for the supply, can this be an point? why they did not used a symmetric voltage?

@Behnam at this point it totally makes sense to raise a new post and open these new questions to all-comers. You don't need to go through the history but, you ought to link it back to this Q and A. You should also release a PCB image to see if there are any anomalies in how things are laid out.

@ thank you Andy, i just made it, i added the layout as well: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/708779/transimpedance-amplifier-with-opa838-oscillation-supply-voltage

Hello @Andy aka I also noticed the output of the OPA838 is connected to a connector for measurement (No load is connected to OPA838) and the trace on the PCB has a capacitance around 170 pF, can this cause the instability? if yes, how can I do a quick test? to verify this is the issue?

You should add that as part of your new question but, make sure that people clearly see it as an edit so that already given answers to that question won't be judged by this late edition.
