Transimpedance amplifier with OPA838 - oscillation - supply voltage
This post is the continuation of my previous post:
Transimpedance amplifier with OPA838 - instability
Considering there were a lot of discussion, so we made this new post, to add for details, such as PCB layout and schematic, and more experimental data:
I have a TIA designed with OPA838 as follows:

This is my layout as well (8- layers PCB), there 63 identical design on the PCB:


Baes on the all of the stability criteria the system should be stable (there is 54 degree positive phase margin), but when I used +/- 2V for the supply voltage, current consumption form positive rail 360mA (5.7mA each OPA838), current consumption form negative rail 357mA(5.66mA each OPA838), considering I have 63 identical OPA838 circuit on my PCB, for out put of each OPA838- I see a oscillations in the outputs follows:

When I reduced the voltage to +/-1V there is not oscillation anymore, current consumption form positive rail 67.9mA, current consumption form negative rail 67.7mA,) . Besides, when I use (V-=0 & V+=3.5V, the current consumption is 146.7mA (each OPA838 about 2.3mA) and I did not see any oscillation in the output!? In the OPA838 datasheet, the transimpedance part they have used (V-=-230mV, V+= 3V) for the supply, can this be an point? why they did not used a symmetric voltage? and a very small value for the negative  rail?

Recommended layout by datasheet

Please let me know what can be the issue?

You should add a link to the previous question and explain why this new question is not a partial duplicate. Duplicate's are not particularly well-received by anyone. In other words, spend 5 minutes adding a few words about why this question has evolved from the previous question and, has a right to exist in its own right.

Hello Andy Done

Is the power supply rail also oscillating. Look carefully for this because it may only be a few milli volts

Because you have exceeded absolute maximum voltage supply in the past, the chip is simply not guaranteed to ever function to spec, ever again.  Replace the op amp before trying  in-range supplies or further debugging.

The datasheet explains the use of the -230mV negative rail:  "Here, a fixed –0.23 negative voltage generator (LM7705) is used on the negative supply to make sure the output has adequate headroom when the output is at 0 V."  If you made the negative rail 0V the opamp would saturate when there was a weak signal.  You probably don't see oscillation at 2V because the minimum supply is 2.7V, so even if you're testing a blown up amp it is probably off at that voltage.

@ user1850479 thank you for the comment, I did not mentioned that the circuit is not oscillating when I used 2V, but I used these voltages V-=0V, V+= 3.5V, so the OPA838 is fully on, the point is that when I do not use any negative voltage, I Do not see any oscillation, and do not know why? why the datasheet suggested to use (V-=-230mV, V+= 3V) for Transimpedance application, which is my application? Do you think adding C22 has cause an issue?

@ Scott Seidman, thank you for the contribution, I applied a signal to the input of the OPA838, when the supply is +/-1V, and noticed, it is amplifying  the voltage, so, can we say, OPA838 is alive?

@Behnam: While you did remove the ground plane from beneath the out put and inverting input pins, The traces connecting to those pins are still over the ground and power planes. The example in the datasheet removes the planes from the entire path connected to those pins. The chips pinout is not the best in my opinion, but  to work with it is important. Running the output trace under the chip is not advisable. The trace to the connector should include a small resistor as suggested by others. This resistor should be placed as close to the output pin as possible.

@Behnam: The feedback resistor looks to be very small. Good for noise but not stability. See the frequency response charts in the data sheet. Remove the thermal relief from the vias. Especially for ground connections. If I have time I will post a suggested layout

@ RussellH thank you, very useful comment, I would appreciate if you can post a reference layout, would you please let me know how can I be notified once you post it?

@RussellH I have a question regarding removing the ground plane underneath the feedback race, if I remove the GND plane, then it is possible that I loose my return path for feedback signal? I add the recommended layout by datasheet in this post, but I can not see where it is mentioned that I need to remove GND plane from underneath the feedback trace? Would you please explain it a bit more?

@RussellH you mentioned that "The chips pinout is not the best", so would you please let me know what package is the best option? then I can replace it in my new layout.

Not to beat the dead horse, but did you seriously put 64 of those on an expensive PCB without trying a cheap 4-layer small prototype first? Hopefully this was the last time you made that mistake :) As you can see, trying to "save time" by not prototyping will almost always not save any time, and end up with an expensive paperweight.

@Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica, Hi, yes I did, but I was asked to do so, my intention was to porotype first, but management team ask me to do so..

@Andromeda Maybe you need to talk to someone above the management to make them aware that said management is wasting company money by making basic engineering decisions backwards, and that's saying it gently. I know it's not always possible, but if it's a private company, there may be a way of doing it. Such management is counter-productive. You probably know it, but I want you to know that we're on your side here.

I would go with the suggestion to use a virtual ground and power the op-amp from a single supply. Much fewer parasitics on the power supply that way.

Note that all input pins are resistively decoupled from parasitics. R4 could be 0Ω, but I'd start with 20-100Ω first.
I would do it on a small 1x1" 4-layer prototype to evaluate performance first.
Top layer has most components except the feedback path. Bottom layer (blue) has the feedback path components, to minimize stray capacitances.

1st inner layer has +5V:

2nd inner layer has GND:

The bottom layer would have +2V5 (virtual ground) distribution etc.

thanks for the effort you made, I really appreciate it, I will give it try to see if we can solve this issue, thanks again

You are using SOT23 package with 1.3mm pitch. The trace from output to C4R4 looks like 0.4 mm wide, and the length is about 6.5 mm.
According to this calculator,

So you effectively have a 33nH inductor in your feedback path.
I suspect this unwanted component will change your stability analysis.
ADDITION/CORRECTION: There are a couple of more things to consider:

Given the actual substrate thickness of 0.12mm, the parasitic inductance does go lower, maybe to 6-10nH, true;
No void under the components near (V-) input adds about 3pF of parasitic capacitance to ground;
Multilayer Ceramic caps like 100nF don't work as capacitors above 20MHz, they act as inductors. (The scope shows oscillations at ~90MHz). This needs to be accurately included into stability analysis.



Reducing supply voltage of the amplifier reduces its gain, so it is well understandable that the parasitic oscillations vanish.

In summary, this is a classic example of poor choice of OPA for the task and inadequate layout. It is a good demonstration of old engineering saying: "oscillators don't, amplifiers do"

@ Ale..chenski thank you very much for the contribution, very interesting point, my layout is 8 layers PCB, the exact values you use used in the calculator are as follows: Substrate High (Prepreg)=0.12mm, Trace width= 0.2mm, Trace Thickness= 0.035, Trace length= 6.5mm, so it would be around 6nH, can this value be effective to making an LC oscillation ?

Regarding the PCB layout this was the introduction in the datasheet: Ground or power planes must be removed from directly under the negative input and output pins of the amplifier. and I did the same thing, I removed GND under the negative input and output pins.

@Behnam, yes, making voids under input pads is a must. However, please notice the trace width in their reference evaluation designs - they are extremely wide, something like 1.5mm. As I understand, you did an analysis of your circuit. Why don 't you add 6nH into the feedback network and re-run the analysis?

thank you for the interesting point, would you please let me know what would be the effect of adding a 6nH into the feedback network? (I want to point  this out also that I have this issue when I have +/- supply voltage higher than 1.2V, but when it is less than +/-1.2V and or it is  (V-=0 V, V+= 3V). In fact when I use a negative voltage in my negative supply pin, I have oscillation,  can it be something wrong with C22 in between positive and negative supply pin? there is also 3 nH in between the positive and negative supply pins.

@ Ale..chenski I did the simulation and even having a 300nH inductor was still ok, and I did not seen any  oscillation. So, we can conclude that feedback layout is ok, but I have doubt about the C22 in between positive and negative supply!

Wow, this calculator is off by almost an order of magnitude; ah -- notice the W >> H approximation. You need a microstrip calculator for these values.
