Adding a capacitor between positive and negative supply pin can cause stability issue in OpAmp circuit?
I have a transimpedance amplifier designed and when I apply  +/- 2V to its supply pins it is oscillating, I noticed when I apply GND to V- supply pin, it does not oscillate, so I have a little bit doubt about capacitor (C22) that I have added between between positive and negative supply pin. I checked with a impedance calculator based on my PCB layout, there is 4nH inductor because of the PCB track in between positive and negative supply pin:

Can this cap cause any issue? datasheet also suggested to have this cap in between positive and negotiate supply pins.

How large is C22? Calculate the resonant frequency with 4 nH, and likely that would be far beyond the IC's frequency capability! Look elsewhere for instability.

There is not much to say without schematic and datasheet, but you often have less issues using a separate capacitor for each supply rail.

@ DrMoishe Pippik Thank you for the comment, C22=100nF, the oscillation that I see is around 85 MHz, would you please see more details about the schematic and the datasheet here? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/708779/transimpedance-amplifier-with-opa838-oscillation-supply-voltage/708806?noredirect=1#comment1885895_708806
Please not that I have 63 of this circuit in one PCB, the PCB is 8 layers.

@DrMoishe Pippik the issue is the when I see my output with a another devices (USB-oscilloscope ) than normal oscilloscope, I see my input signal amplification and the amplification is very well. I think the reason is that this USB-oscilloscope has some filtering steps on the input signal, but the normal oscilloscope does not have it, so by the normal oscilloscope I just see the oscillation, which you can see here.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/708779/transimpedance-amplifier-with-opa838-oscillation-supply-voltage/708806?noredirect=1#comment1885895_708806 .

@ DrMoishe Pippik then I though, the amplification is being done correctly  but I also see an unwanted oscillation on the output of the OPA838, so can it be the power supply issue?

@Jens Please see all the details here:             https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/708779/transimpedance-amplifier-with-opa838-oscillation-supply-voltage/708806?noredirect=1#comment1885895_708806    . Please not that I have 63 of the same circuit on my 8 layers PCB.
