Investigating the effect of PCB layout parasitic in an op-amp amplifier by simulation
Would you please let me know what components I should add to my schematic as result of PCB parasitic to make my simulation more accurate?
As an example, the following image shows an amplifier schematic in TINA-TI simulation software. What components (C, L, R, ...) should I add extra to this simulation file as a result of PCB/layout parasitic? And where should I place them?

Schematic:

Layout:

Layer stack up:


First you have to characterize the parasitics and decide if they will have any significant impact on your circuit.  Every trace has an associated capacitance and inductance, but they aren't necessarily big enough to warrant adding components to a simulation.  Sometimes it's critical, often it's not.

Without seeing your layout, how can we start to guess which parasitics might be important?

FYI to readers, OP has given a partial layout here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/708779/transimpedance-amplifier-with-opa838-oscillation-supply-voltage though perhaps it has been changed since then. It's worth noting this is another in a string of questions; check their profile for details. (I would link all of them for posterity, but I don't think it would actually clarify anything, honestly.)  To OP: it matters precisely what and where the photodiode is placed, cable length and impedance, trace length and impedance/geometry, etc. And what's connected to the output.

It may even matter what's connected to the supply, outside of the immediate capacitors; there are simply details we cannot know, and we need to know the topology -- the connections and layout -- to be able to transform them into lumped-equivalent RLC values, if they can be (meaningfully) transformed at all in this case.

@ The Photon I edited the previous post and added layout and schematic.

One important parasitic missing in your schematic is the load capacitance on the output: if it is a long trace it can be significant, so you may need an isolation resistor. Also I see you cut the ground plane under some of the pads but then you use a wide trace for output which increases capacitance. If you put the 2 feedback components where "B4" is written, trace will be shorter. And I have no idea where the via on pin 1 is going...

Dear @bobflux thank you for the nice and useful comment yes, the output of the OPA is connected with a via to layer 3 with long track (125 mm) , then it is connected to a connector for measurement. I will consider adding that resistor. In the datasheet I saw it is mentioned "Place feedback resistor on the bottom of PCB between pins 4 and 6", do you think it is need to put it on the bottom layer? or my current layout is ok? do I need to remove the ground plane as well under the feedback trace?

For simulation accuracy you need an accurate opamp model. Some models are quite simplified and only include the basics like open loop gain/phase and output impedance. Sometimes, the output is a controlled voltage source with a resistor in series. Other stages of the opamp may be modeled with controlled current sources or behavioral sources. And some models include a hidden internal ground connection.
So if the opamp model doesn't include an actual output stage with transistor models, but is a controlled source instead, then output current will not come from the model's supply pins but from the hidden ground pin! In this case, you can forget about checking the opamp's interaction with its own power supply. It will be completely insensitive to power supply impedance.
Sometimes it models PSRR, but not always. In some models, you don't even get clipping and the output will happily swing beyond the rails.
When the output of a rail to rail opamp gets close to the rails, one of the output transistors gets its Vce/Vds squeezed, so its performance will drop, so the opamp's performance depends on the sign of output current and which transistor in the push pull is driving the output. Of course that is not modeled if the output stage is not modeled...
Simulated voltage sources have zero impedance. Thus, simulated decoupling caps are useless, unless you also model the output impedance of your voltage source, traces (and caps) by adding inductors.
Anyway, interaction of the opamp with load capacitance should be modeled as this is really important and common stuff. But it doesn't hurt to check the "frequency response with capacitive load" graph in the datasheet, build the same circuit in your simulator, and see if you actually get the same results. If you do then fine, you can use it.

the output of the OPA is connected with a via to layer 3 with long track (125 mm) , then it is connected to a connector for measurement.

You can use a PCB trace impedance calculator to get the impedance and capacitance of that transmission line and model it with a SPICE transmission line. Or just add a capacitor at the output to model trace capacitance. Then the cable will have capacitance too. Most likely you will get peaking in your frequency response, perhaps even instability.
If the trace goes to a connector with a 50 ohm coax, the best is to route the trace as 50 ohms (copper is free, just set the proper width) to avoid reflection on the connector. Then add a source resistor very close to the opamp to isolate it from the capacitance and also terminate the transmission line so you don't get signal integrity issues.
Inductance in series with the input signal can also matter (trace from C5) as it adds to the input impedance of your virtual ground. Also your opamp is not unity gain stable, it requires a gain of 6. So if you put a capacitor in the feedback, you will only get the required gain if C14 has 6x more cacitance than C1 (which is the case) and the inductance of your signal source is low enough that C14 still looks like a cap and not an inductor at the unity loop gain frequency, which is not guaranteed if there's a long trace or cable.

In the datasheet I saw it is mentioned "Place feedback resistor on the bottom of PCB between pins 4 and 6"

You're using 4 layer so the bottom layer is about 1.4mm away from the ground plane on layer 2, and top layer is 0.2mm away. So if you put the feedback resistor and caps on bottom layer their pads will have much lower capacitance to ground than on top layer.
So if you plan to put components on the bottom, then these should be on the bottom, and you can route V+ on top layer below the opamp, and put the decoupling caps on top:

Note it's not a good idea to use the same via for the decoupling caps and the opamp's ground reference input, as output current flows through the decoupling caps and to the vias. It's better to use a via to ground plane just for the IN+ pin.
The 100nF cap is the same size as the 2.2µF cap thus it has the same inductance, which means it doesn't bring any benefit at high frequency. If you use all caps of the same size, just put 1µF caps. If you really want to put 100nF, then pick a much smaller package. It won't matter because the inductance of opamp package and bond wires is much higher than the cap anyway, so all you get for using 2 caps in parallel is a resonance peak.
Otherwise if your board is populated only on top side, then you should put the feedback where "B4" is, with the cap closest to the chip, skinny traces for low capacitance, and perhaps make a hole in the ground plane under the pads. Something like that:


@ bobflux thank you so, much, it was very useful. For clarification in this part, would you please let me know if you mean by C14, C4? because C14 in the Altium schematic is decoupling capacitor.

@ bobflux Regarding the PCB layers, I use 8 layer board from Euro circuit. I added the stack up in the edited post . so I think I will get the same capacitance, if I put the the feedback cap and trace in the bottom based on the stack up right? Them I will have to use via from he PIN 4 and PIN 1 to the bottom layer, is it a god idea to use via in the feedback loop trace? ( by the way we need to accept this fact that datasheet motioned to put the cap on the bottom)

@ bobflux Regarding the decoupling cap: The 100nF cap is the same size as the 2.2µF cap. followed what the datasheet has mentioned: 0.1-μF decoupling capacitors. A larger capacitor (2.2 µF is typical) is used with a high-frequency, 0.1-µF supply decoupling capacitor at the device supply pins.

@ bobflux If I move C31 and C32 a to be  close to C22, then  they will be far from PIN 2, do we need to keep them as close as possible to the supply pin ? the same question for C13 and  C14, they will be far from PIN 6.

I used part numbers from the TINA schematic. The capacitance you get depends on whether there is a power/ground plane or not below your pad, so it depends what you put on those layers. Via inductance should not be a problem, it will be less than long trace. Regarding capacitor placement, what matters is total inductance in the loop: V- - chip - V+ - caps - ground. And 100nF has the same HF performance as 1µF or 2µF if the package is the same.
